# Storing User Login Time in a User Table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, database

In a table of Users, I want to keep track of the time of day each user logs in as running totals. For example

```
UserID    midnightTo6am    6amToNoon    noonTo6pm    6pmToMidnight
User1     3                2            7            1
User2     4                9            1            8
```

Note that this is *part of a larger table that contains more information about a user*, such as address and gender, hair color, etc, etc.

In this example, what is the best way to store this this data? Should it be part of the users table, despite knowing that not every user will log in at every time (a user may never log in between 6am and noon)? Or is this table a 1NF failure because of repeating columns that should be moved to a separate table?

If stored as part of the Users Table, there may be empty cells that never get populated with data because the user never logs in at that time.

If this data is a 1NF failure and the data is to be put in a separate table, how would I ensure that a +1 for a certain time goes smoothly? Would I search for the user in the separate table to see if they have logged in at that time before and +1? Or add a column to that table if it is their first time logging in during that time period?

Any clarifications or other solutions are welcome!

Comment: What are the numbers that you added to table? are they hours? If yes, So why don't you store them as a single column and do your decision in PHP?

Comment: The numbers added to the table are just sample login amounts. For instance, User1 logged in a total of 3 times between midnight and 6am.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend storing the login events either in a file based log or in a simple table with just the userid and DATETIME of the login.

Once a day, or however often you need to report on the data you illustrated in your question, aggregate that data up into a table in the shape that you want. This way you're not throwing away any raw data and can always reaggregate for different periods, by hour, etc at a later date.

addition: I suspect that the fastest way of deriving the aggregated data would be to run a number of range queries for each of your aggregation periods so you're searching for (e.g.) login dates in the range `2011-12-25 00:00:00 - 2011-12-24 03:00:00`. If you go with that approach and index of (datetime, user_id) would work well. It seems counter-intuitive as you want to do stuff on a user-centric basis but the index on the DATETIME field would allow easy finding of the rows and then the trailing user_id index would allow for fast grouping.

Comment: This is more a question of normalization and the proper way to store the data in regards to a User Table. I'm trying to avoid storing redundant data.

Comment: I agree with this. The current schema is not flexible, so if for some reason you wanted to see people that logged in between 3pm and 9pm, you couldn't do it. With @James C's suggestion, you aren't losing any data granularity. I don't think you really even need to aggregate the data, frankly. Just build a report and let it run. If the table is indexed correctly on the user id column, the COUNT() operation will be quick.

Comment: More specifically, I'm looking for the best way to store this data. Being stored in the User Table, there would be empty cells if the user doesn't ever log in during a specified time period. Stored in its own table, this data would be subject to various SQL searches and updates. I'm looking for the most efficient, best logical way.

Comment: Explain why you couldn't see people that are logged in between 3pm and 9pm.

Comment: I agree with this too. You can even do more stuff around the logged date and time. Something like get the activity percentage and ... -user - the best way is what @James C said. You can do your decision in the SQL command or even in PHP as I said by a single DATETIME field.

Comment: @user James's solution is the defacto standard, and most logical way to do this. Efficiency can mean many things, so you would need to clarify that.

Comment: By efficiency, I mean storing the data in a normalized form.

Comment: @user: because you've lost data granularity by aggregating a count into specific columns. If someone logged in 5 times between noon and 6 pm, and 3 times between 6pm and midnight, then with your current schema you would not be able to derive the number of times they logged in between 3pm and 9pm because you didn't track exact timestamps.

Comment: To clarify, this is mora theoretical question based on the principles of normalization as opposed to a practical one. I'm looking for the most normal way to do this.

Comment: Normalized is usually the opposite of efficient, if you're speaking about performance. However, it is often the most flexible and useful. For your specific scenario, what if you wanted to store what IP address someone logged in from to prevent hackers? Well, you simply can't do that with your current schema, but it would be a piece of cake to do it with James's proposed schema.

Comment: In general, think of your database as being full of objects. Is a user login an attribute of a user? No, probably not, so store it in a new table. Is an email address an attribute of a user? Well, that will depend on whether you want the system to support multiple email addresses. What about hair color? That is certainly an attribute of a user, unless you also wanted to store hair color history. Basically, if an object has an attribute, you store it in the same table. If it's actually another object or list of objects, you normalize the data by storing it in another table.

Comment: I think you get a nice balance of usability with my solution without having to throw away any data. A regular aggregation into a separate table wouldn't be particularly computationally heavy but might be something that you don't want to do at runtime if the "raw log" table gets really large. Having his normalised, aggregated data in a separate table indexed by user id would be very cheap to fetch, finding the row using the index would be cheap and then it's just a simple, small sequential read to fetch the data.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things.  Firstly, this is not a violation of 1NF. Doing it as 4 columns may in fact be acceptable.   Secondly, if you do go with this design, you should not use nulls, use zero instead(with the possible exception of existing records).  Finally, WHETHER you should use this design or split it into another table (or two) is dependent upon your purpose and usage.  If your standard use of the table does not make use of this information, it should go into another table with a 1 to 1 relationship.  If you may need to increase the granuality of the login times, then you should use another table. Finally, if you do split this off into another table with a timestamp, give some consideration to privacy.